# Can you use Classes as values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

Fairly new to programming, and I am trying to make an id system, which is basically:

```
...
     enum ids
     {
          id1,
          id2,
          id3
     }

     Dictionary<ids, _____> IdDictionary = new Dictionary<ids, _____>()
     { 
           {0, Id1Class}
           {1, Id2Class}
           {2, Id3Class}
     }

class Id1Class
{
     //some data
}

class Id2Class
{
     //some data
}

class Id3Class
{
     //some data
}
...
```

That's want I want to do. The idea is that an enum contains the Id, and the dictionary assigns the data types (in this case, I am trying to make province system, so for say a random one in say... Germany, the enum would assign the id, and using the id, the dictionary would set it to that province, with things like population and such). I assumed that this would be a way to do it, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what to put in the part declaring the type of the dictionary's values. Maybe the namespace or something? Or make it a method or something? Not sure.

I want `IdDictionary[ids.id1]` to return the *class* `Id1Class`.

Comment: Some ropey naming going on there.. Recommend PascalCase for `Dictionary`, enum name `Ids`, enum member names, don't name enum in the plural becaise it's not a flags, add a semicolon after dictionary init, instantiate some classes (if those IdX in the dict initializer are type names, it won't work... Consider much better names than X1, X2 etc, do not use "class" in class name, add missing type for dictionary value..

Comment: Do you need to get the type itself or a certain object?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E8xljG

Comment: As you are new, you'll need to be more precise with your terminology to get a good answer. When you say return the *class* do you mean each class's Type (System.Type) or do you mean an instance of each class (aka an object)?

Comment: Side note: the example (" I am trying to make province system...") does not in any way suggest that multiple classes had to be involved... It looks like you want `class Province {string Name}` and dictionary of `Province` objects indexed by name like `(new[]{new Province{Name= "Bavar"}}).ToDictionary(p=> p.Name, p=>p);`

Comment: Reguarding the naming, I named it how I did so it was just generic.

I just now remembered objects, so for the second comment, object now I guess so I don't need as many classes (399 of them I would need...)

comment 4, orginally was trying to get a class type, but now remembering objects, objects now.

comment 5, not sure what the `p=>`, `p.Name`, and `p=>p` means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can!  Here you go:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<ids, Type> IdDictionary = new Dictionary<ids, Type>()
    { 
       {ids.id1, typeof(Id1Class)},
       {ids.id2, typeof(Id2Class)},
       {ids.id3, typeof(Id3Class)}
    };
    
    Console.WriteLine(IdDictionary[ids.id1]);
    Console.WriteLine(IdDictionary[ids.id2]);
    Console.WriteLine(IdDictionary[ids.id3]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Program+Id1Class
Program+Id2Class
Program+Id3Class
```

**Explanation:**

The problem you were running into is that you wanted to use the *classes themselves* as the values for the dictionary, ***not*** *individual instances/objects* of those classes.  When you're first introduced to dictionaries, this may not be explained yet.

To do this, you need to take these classes and treat them as individual objects, rather than overall types.  In C#, classes (as well as other things, such as structs) are themselves instances of `Type`.  So to treat a class as an instance, you can use `typeof(<ClassName>)`, and you will get the object representation of that class.

So in your example above:

1. The second generic parameter to the dictionary should be `Type`.
2. `Dictionary` itself should be capitalized.
3. `typeof(Id1Class)`, `typeof(Id2Class)`, and `typeof(Id3Class)` should be used to get the object/instance representations of those classes.  In that way, you can pass the classes around like ordinary data, using them as arguments to functions and whatever else you want.  In this case, you can do this to populate your dictionary.
4. Forgot to mention: Also use things like `ids.id1` and `ids.id2`, instead of things like `0` and `1`.  Sipo reminded me by including this point in their (upvoted) answer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was a Type, and instead though it was its own thing, so thank you for that, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand the underlying real-world problem, but I have a feeling that you are trying to solve it the wrong way.

First of all, why would you want to return the types themselves? It seems to me like each province should be an **object** of a `Province` class and not a class by itself.

Secondly, this sort of "matching" you are trying to do between two values **screams** *polymorphism*. Since you are a beginner, I assume these concepts are not familiar to you, so I encourage you to read about them because they are fundamental to solving these sorts of real-world problems.

But to answer your question as questioned, I will simply use a `switch` statement:

```
Type IdToType(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case 0:
            return typeof(Id1Class);

        case 1:
            return typeof(Id1Class);

        case 2:
            return typeof(Id1Clas);
    }
}
```

And if you really want to use the enum, you could change the numeric literal to the enum values (since an `enum` is simply a wrapper around integers):

```
enum Ids
{
    Id1,
    Id2,
    Id3
}

Type IdToType(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case Ids.Id1:
            return typeof(Id1Class);

        case Ids.Id2:
            return typeof(Id1Class);

        case Ids.Id3:
            return typeof(Id1Class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "an object of a `Province` class and not a class by itself", so sorry about that.

I don't think I need to return the types, and instead, I need to assign a class to a name/id in an enum so I can assign values (like in my province thing, so I can give it an integer like say population, and when I need that, I reference the id in the dictionary or something, and get the data for what I need)

Edit: Think I understand now, you mean to do something like `Province provinceName = new Province`?

Comment: Yup. Do you understand the difference between a class and an object?

Comment: A class defines whats in an object, while an object creates a new instance of the class, with whats in the class?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Based on your comments, I believe there is a gap in your C# knowledge, and that it is the source of your questions. I think you would benefit from learning the basics of C# (classes, objects, properties, etc) and Object-Oriented Programming.